# How to use Faker gem without a model in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, faker

First time posting here. I currently have a Ruby on Rails project in which I have a PostgreSQL database. I recently created a table in the PostgreSQL database and I wanted to generate fake data to populate it. The problem is that the way I usually do it is by using the model, which I don't have for my table in my PostgreSQL database. I'd usually do something like:

```
50.times do
  Model.create({ ...properties })
end
```

How would I go about it if I don't have the model? Is it possible to do it with the table name? If I just use the table name (which doesn't have a model), I get this error: `NameError: uninitialized constant`.

Any help is appreciated :)

aburr answered my question perfectly!

Comment: Why are you trying to test data that falls outside the scope of your app's business logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought if you do not have a model or class of any kind associated with the SQL table then you may be able to execute a SQL `insert` statement.

maybe something like this

```
require 'pg'
require 'faker'

db =  PG.connect({:dbname => 'my_db_name'})

50.times do
  db.exec("insert into Users (name) values(#{Faker::Name.name}")
end
```

Here is the Faker Readme https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/master/README.md#usage

and a reference for using SQL with Ruby http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqlruby/

Comment: You're missing quotes around the value, and the `#{}` necessary for it to be evaluated as code. To avoid this, and a pile of security holes, use [`exec_params`](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-exec_params). `db.exec_params('insert into users (name) values ($1)', [Faker::Name.name])`.

Comment: You're still missing the quotes around the name value. Consider `insert into Users (name) values('Some name')`. Note the quotes around `Some name`. Since you're passing in a string you need to add those quotes. You also need to escape the name in case `Sean O'Exploit` signs up. `db.exec("insert into Users (name) values('#{db. escape_string(Faker::Name.name)}'")`. Again, don't add values to queries with strings. Use parameters. It avoids a whole bunch of bugs and [one of these most common security holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: Doing it like this worked! Simply doing something along the lines of '#{Faker::Name.name}' litereally inside the values!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend making a model for the table. It's trivial. If you're on Rails 6, you can make use of [`insert_all`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all) to do the creation significantly faster.

```
class SomeThing < ApplicationRecord
end
```

If you want to forego that, you can use [`exec_insert`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/DatabaseStatements.html#method-i-exec_insert) to perform the insert manually.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_insert(
  'insert into some_thing (first_name, last_name) values ($1, $2)',
  nil,
  [[nil, Faker::Name.first_name], [nil, Faker::Name.last_name]]
);
```

Finally, rather than writing `50.times { SomeThing.create(...) }` manually, consider using [`FactoryBot`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md).

```
factory :some_thing do
  name { Faker::Name.name }
end

FactoryBot.create_list(:some_thing, 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't about gem 'faker', actually it's a fake data generator. So the problem is about ActiveRecord, you need to find out the docs about [ActiveRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#the-active-record-pattern).
Typically, `Model.create(foo: 'bar')` means `insert into Model (foo) values('bar')`.
So ActiveRecord has raw sql operations in case you have some more complicated scenarios `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`.
If you have any chance to use the gem `sequel`, you will get more understanding behind the scene.

- Database (MySQL, PG)
- Database connector (mysql2, pg)
- ORM (ActiveRecord, Sequel)

That's all you need to handle the database.